# Multiple buttons on webpage are invoking all button actions

Tags: php, html

I have two submission buttons on my webpage which are assigned to do different things. My problem is that clicking 1 of the buttons is invoking the actions of both buttons. How can I make it so that clicking 1 button only invokes the associated form submission action?

(This is my first day using php).

**First form:**

```
<form id="frm1" onsubmit="document.getElementById('frm1').submit();">
    <center><br>
        <input style="width:150px" name="data" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add Time (hh:mm:ss)">
        </input>
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
        <input name="addTime" type="hidden" value="true">
        <button style="width:40px" type="submit" class='btn btn-success pull-right'>
          <i class="icon-plus"></i>
        </button
</form>
```

**Second form:**

```
<form id="frm2" onsubmit="document.getElementById('frm2').submit();">
    <center>
        Edit Group:
        <?php
            #

            $styles = sqlToQuery("SELECT groupID, Name from sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_map_job_group");

            echo '<select style="width:100" name="groupNum">';

            for($i = 0; $i < count($styles); $i ++){
                echo ' <option style="width:100" value="'.$styles[$i][0].'">'.$styles[$i][1].'</option>';       
            }

            echo '</select><br>';                           
        ?>

        <input name="editGroup" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-info pull-right'>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit Group&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </button>
</form>
```

**Checking if buttons are submitted:**

```
if ($_GET['addTime']==='true'){
    sqlToQuery("replace into sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_map_jobtimes (job_ID, time_to_run) values (".$ID." ,'".$_GET['data']."')");
    echo '<script>window.location.assign("'.$redir.'?id='.$ID.'");</script>';
}

if ($_GET['editGroup']==='true'){
    sqlToQuery("UPDATE sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_jobs a SET a.group = '".$_GET['groupNum']."' WHERE a.job_ID = ".$ID." ");
    echo '<script>window.location.assign("'.$redir.'?id='.$ID.'");</script>';
}
```

Comment: In your frm1 button tag is not closed. _</button_ is it typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first form, button tag is not closed properly, that's why first form is tag is not closed properly,use this,

```
<form id="frm1" onsubmit="document.getElementById('frm1').submit();">
    <center><br>
        <input style="width:150px" name="data" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add Time (hh:mm:ss)">
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>">
        <input name="addTime" type="hidden" value="true">
        <button style="width:40px" type="submit" class='btn btn-success pull-right'>
          <i class="icon-plus"></i>
        </button>
     </center>   
</form>
```

Also change your php code like this

```
if ( isset($_GET['addTime']) && $_GET['addTime']==='true'){
    sqlToQuery("replace into sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_map_jobtimes (job_ID, time_to_run) values (".$ID." ,'".$_GET['data']."')");
    echo '<script>window.location.assign("'.$redir.'?id='.$ID.'");</script>';
}

if ( isset($_GET['editGroup']) &&  $_GET['editGroup']==='true'){
    sqlToQuery("UPDATE sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_jobs a SET a.group = '".$_GET['groupNum']."' WHERE a.job_ID = ".$ID." ");
    echo '<script>window.location.assign("'.$redir.'?id='.$ID.'");</script>';
}
```

Comment: </input> is not necessary :)

Comment: @Ekin Thanks I have update my ans, I just checked with button tag only.

Answer (score 1):

Give you're submit buttons a `value` and a `name` catch the different values using `$_GET`(in your case) or `$_POST`

Update: (just to give it a try maybe)

**First Form**

```
<form id="frm1" action="" method="post">
    <center><br>
        <input style="width:150px" name="data" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Add Time (hh:mm:ss)" />
        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
        <input style="width:50px" type="submit" class='btn btn-success pull-right' name="submit_form1" value="submit" />
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </center>
</form>
```

**Second Form**

```
<form id="frm2" name="frm2" action="" method="post">
    <center>
        Edit Group:
        <?php
        $styles = sqlToQuery("SELECT groupID, Name from sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_map_job_group");

        echo '<select style="width:100" name="groupNum">';

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($styles); $i ++)
        {
            echo ' <option style="width:100" value="' . $styles[$i][0] . '">' . $styles[$i][1] . '</option>';
        }

        echo '</select><br>';
        ?>
        <input type="submit" class='btn btn-info pull-right' name="submit_form2" value="Submit Group" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit_form1"))
{
    // {Check for empty var on data}

    sqlToQuery("replace into sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_map_jobtimes (job_ID, time_to_run) values (" . $ID . " ,'" . $_GET['data'] . "')");
    echo '<script>window.location.assign("' . $redir . '?id=' . $ID . '");</script>';
}

if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "submit_form2"))
{
    sqlToQuery("UPDATE sha_scheduler_dev.sha_scheduler_jobs a SET a.group = '" . $_GET['groupNum'] . "' WHERE a.job_ID = " . $ID . " ");
    echo '<script>window.location.assign("' . $redir . '?id=' . $ID . '");</script>';
}
?>
```

This is pretty tight and keeps your url clean.

Comment: how does one use $_POST to catch the different values ?

Comment: In your case get since your form uses get

Comment: notice that my if statements already use get. What is wrong with them?

Comment: Nothing, i would prefer post because it doesnt stuff your url. But besides that you can catch the variables in the same way. '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="btn1" >' catch by '$_GET["submit"]' and ofcource btn2 or something else for the other submit btn

Comment: So I catch by if($_GET["submit'] == value) for example?

Comment: Yes, value is like btn1 in example i gave for btn1 :-) try it

Comment: Oh and remove the onsubmit line.. If submit button is pressed the form is already being submitted

Comment: Even better '<form id="frn1" action="" method="post" >' and use post instead of get

Comment: Unfortunately, the buttons don't execute the commands anymore

Comment: See my last post, you had no action set

Comment: What do I assign to action?

Comment: The page you want to send the form to. Just empty as in my example is your case

Comment: If the button is pushed I would like the appropriate if statement to be executed.

Comment: `If ($_POST["submit"] == "btn1 or whathever the value is"){ //your action }`

Comment: So I have: '<form id="frm1" action="" method="post" >' and '    <button style="width:40px" type="submit" class='btn btn-success pull-right' name="time" value=1>' and if statement is: 'if ($_POST["submit"]=='1')'

Comment: but still nothing happens when I press the button! I am desperate for this to work!

Comment: Can you add thus button and test please, without edditing or adding content to it: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="it works" />` and catch with `echo "result: " . $_POST["submit"];`